# How can I make this jQuery object script easier?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started to realize if I would start to add more different stuff in that object I will have to add more code to

where it said's `output += element.item + '<br>' + element.cost + '<br>';`

So how do I make this code where I don't have to type out additional code to that area that I'm planing to add to that object to output?

I know there is a way where you don't have to type out additional code for that area every time for example if I would add this additionally (element.events etc..) I would have to type out more additional code to that area which will take more time and look like this which i'm trying to avoid for example.

```
element.item + '<br>' + element.cost + '<br>' + element.events + '<br>';
```

etc... So I need a new solution so the code can automatically output all the objects contents so I don't have to type out new additional code where it said's

```
output += element.item + '<br>' + element.cost + '<br>';
```

Here' my code that i'm talking about.

```js
var data = {
  shop: [{
      item: "Ps3",
      cost: "$150"
    },
    {
      item: "xbox 360",
      cost: "$140"
    }
  ]
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var z = $('.z'); // Grab class z to toggle
  var x = $('#x');
  var output = '';
  $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
    output += element.item + '<br>' + element.cost + '<br>';
  });
  x.html(output);
  $("button").click(function() {
    z.toggle(); // Toggle z on button click
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: gold;
}

#x {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.z {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="z">
<h1>Details </h1>
<h2 id="x"></h2>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what's the problem as your current explanation is still vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

What I have done is I loop through all the keys of `element` variable in `data.shop`, thus I will just add a `<br>` tag to each of the values of the element. Its generic and will get the job done!

```js
var data = {
  shop: [{
      item: "Ps3",
      cost: "$150"
    },
    {
      item: "xbox 360",
      cost: "$140"
    }
  ]
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var z = $('.z'); // Grab class z to toggle
  var x = $('#x');
  var output = '';
  $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
    for(var j in element){
      output += element[j] + '<br>' ;
    }
  });
  x.html(output);
  $("button").click(function() {
    z.toggle(); // Toggle z on button click
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: gold;
}

#x {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.z {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="z">
<h1>Details </h1>
<h2 id="x"></h2>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Naren Murali your my new best friend!!! Ha ha ha just what I was looking for. Thanks.